# OpenLayers show interaction style without hovering

Tags: openlayers, modify-interaction

I have been making a simple Modify interaction in OpenLayers, for example

```
var dragInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: new ol.Collection([feature]),
    style: dragStyle
});
```

Can I force the interaction style to stay visible without having to hover over it? I am adjusting the anchor for each marker, which makes it difficult to know where to hover the cursor to actually drag the marker.

Comment: Ok, I was missing the very obvious `pixelTolerance` option, but I would still be interested in a way to show the interaction style without any need for hovering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, you can apply your interaction style to a specific feature by using a selection on the feature attribute and just change the selection criteria when you are ready to work with another feature to determine the best anchor point.  Should be able to also create a function to apply that style when you click on a feature.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I already had the custom style, just needed to reuse it. Thanks.